# MVC Core 2.1.1 dotnet publish now creating .exe in addition to .dll

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, web-deployment

How can I publish a MVC core 2.1.1 app for a specific target (win-64) and 'framework-dependent' as a .dll, not an .exe?  Until recently, publish did not create an exe, only a dll.

- Recently (yesterday) when running 'publish' through Visual Studio, I would target 'Framework-dependent' with 'win-x64' as the target runtime.  This created a dll file but no .exe file.  These files ran on the target web server referencing Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe just fine.
- Now these same publish settings generate both an .exe and .dll files, but I am not able to get these to run (i.e. running "app.exe app.dll" fails).
- The same issue occurs when running from the CLI using dotnet publish.
- This still publishes correctly on my co-worker's system for the same project etc.
- I tried restarting, cleaning out cache, re-clone from the repository to a new directory, verifying the same code publishes correctly on another system.

[image: Visual Studio publish settings]